# Как создать программу, в которой будет использоваться видеосвязь?

Tags: c++builder, c++

Видеосвязь будет сделана так же, как и в Skype. Но главная задача программы будет отличаться.

Но, к сожалению, вообще не имею представления, как реализовать видеоплеер да ещё и видеозвонок на C++. Как это можно сделать? Может, есть какие-то библиотеки или что-то подобное?

Comment: Попробуйте поискать в гугле к примеру бибилотеки для данной задачи. По-моему была даже где-то либа, FreeSkype или что-то в этом духе, или OpenSourceSkype, как рза для ваших целей самое-то наверное будет.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую.

Comment: То есть вы хотите написать альтернативу скайпу, но не имеете представления о потоковом видео? Мне кажется, лучше начать с чего-то попроще.

Comment: Плюсую Владу. Почитайте хоть что такое VoIP вообще, какие бывают реализации телефонии удлаенной.

Comment: Была у меня в студенческие годы подобная лабораторная. Сводилась она к тому что я через определенный интервал времени получал картинку с веб-камеры и посылал ее собеседнику. Если Вам такое подойдет, то могу исходники поискать